# Is posix_fadvise synchronous or asynchronous on linux kernel >= 5?

Tags: linux, posix

I am interested in optimizing disk reads via `posix_fadvise` with `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` option.
Is the function call asynchronous, with pre-fetch to buffer done in background, or will I have to wait for the pre-fetch before return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posix_fadvise` doesn't prefetch any data.  It simply tells the kernel that you'd like to use a certain access pattern.

With `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL`, the kernel will double the readahead size, as mentioned in the manual page.  This is the only action performed synchronously by `posix_fadvise`; any readahead will occur as part of another operation and not as part of this call.